# lightswitch code runs in debug mode but not release mode

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Hi I am experimenting with lightswitch and have some javascript code running on the "created" event of a screen. But it only executes when in debug mode! I cant even alert from there in release mode. what am I missing? ive checked chrome js console and there are no errors in release mode. Just doesn't run the create event. any ideas? i need it to set default values. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

if it helps anyone, in release mode, there was a javascript error in an earlier screen, that was preventing the javascript in future screens from executing. I found the javascript error using Chromes Javascript console. So if anyone has this problem, view JS console from the login page, and watch for any errors. For some reason in debug mode, it will somehow allow the JS to continue to execute after a bug in a previous screen.